# ComboBox, is it possible to have ItemsSource and SelectedValue bound to different sources?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have two different objects that are pointing at each other. The first object represents a division in a company. That object has two collection: Employees, which is all the employees working in the division and Project, which is all the special projects that are in progress within that division. So the first object looks like this:

```
public class Division : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    ObservableCollection<Employee> _employees;
    ObservableCollection<Project> _projects;

    public Division()
    {
        Employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
        Projects = new ObservableCollection<Project>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees
    {
        get { return _employees; }
        set
        {
            if (_employees != value)
            {
                _employees = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Employees"));
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Project> Projects
    {
        get { return _projects; }
        set
        {
            if (_projects != value)
            {
                _projects = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Projects"));
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddNewProject()
    {
        this.Projects.Add(new Project(this));
    }
}
```

Notice that when adding a new project to the division, I pass a reference to the division into that project, which looks like this:

```
public class Project : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    string _projectName;
    DateTime _deadline = DateTime.Now;
    Division _division;
    ObservableCollection<Employee> _members;

    public Project()
    {
        Members = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
    }

    public Project(Division div)
    {
        Members = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
        Division = div;
    }

    public string ProjectName
    {
        get { return _projectName; }
        set
        {
            if (_projectName != value)
            {
                _projectName = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ProjectName"));
            }
        }
    }

    public DateTime Deadline
    {
        get { return _deadline; }
        set
        {
            if (_deadline != value)
            {
                _deadline = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Deadline"));
            }
        }
    }

    public Division Division
    {
        get { return _division; }
        set
        {
            if (_division != value)
            {
                if (_division != null)
                {
                    _division.Employees.CollectionChanged -= members_CollectionChanged;
                }
                _division = value;
                if (_division != null)
                {
                    _division.Employees.CollectionChanged += members_CollectionChanged;
                }
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Division"));
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Employee> Members
    {
        get { return _members; }
        set
        {
            if (_members != value)
            {
                if (_members != null)
                {
                    _members.CollectionChanged -= members_CollectionChanged;
                }
                _members = value;
                if (_members != null)
                {
                    _members.CollectionChanged += members_CollectionChanged;
                }
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Members"));
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Employee> AvailableEmployees
    {
        get
        {
            if (Division != null){
                IEnumerable<Employee> availables =
                from s in Division.Employees
                where !Members.Contains(s)
                select s;

                return new ObservableCollection<Employee>(availables);
            }

            return new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
        }
    }

    void members_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AvailableEmployees"));
    }
}
```

The reason I'm doing it like this is, that the project could have any type of team working on it, but only from within the division. So, when building a dashboard for the division, the manager could select any of the employees to that project but without putting in an employee that is already assigned to it. So, the AvailableEmployees property in the project object always keeps track of who is not already assigned to that project.

The problem I'm having is how to translate this into a UI. The experiment I've done so far looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.Views.TestView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test.Views"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<StackPanel>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Div.Projects}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Background="Transparent"
                        BorderThickness="0, 0, 0, 2"
                        BorderBrush="Black"
                        Margin="0, 0, 0, 5"
                        Padding="0, 0, 0, 5">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding ProjectName}"/>
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Members}">
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:TestView}, Path=DataContext.AvailableEmployees}"
                                              DisplayMemberPath="FirstName"
                                              Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                        <Button Content="Add Employee to Project"
                                Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:TestView}, Path=DataContext.AddEmployeeToProject}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Button Content="Add New Project"
            Command="{Binding AddNewProject}" />
</StackPanel>
```

The view model associated with this view is as follows:

```
public class TestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    private Division _div;

    public TestViewModel(Division div)
    {
        Div = div;

        AddNewProject = new DelegateCommand(OnAddNewProject);
        AddEmployeeToProject = new DelegateCommand<Project>(OnAddEmployeeToProject);
    }

    public DelegateCommand AddNewProject { get; set; }
    public DelegateCommand<Project> AddEmployeeToProject { get; set; }

    public Division Div
    {
        get { return _div; }
        set
        {
            if (_div != value)
            {
                _div = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Div"));
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnAddNewProject()
    {
        Div.AddNewProject();
    }

    private void OnAddEmployeeToProject(Project proj)
    {
        var availables = proj.AvailableEmployees;

        if (availables.Count > 0)
        {
            proj.Members.Add(availables[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I cannot get the combobox for each employee in each project to work. It seems like the selected item/value is bound to the itemssource, and each time the combobox turns out blank. I've tried to do this also with SelectedValue and SelectedItem properties for the combobox, but none worked.

How do I get these two separated. Is there anything else I'm missing here?

Comment: Maybe OT, but why are you raising `PropertyChanged("Class")` when `Div` changes? Also what do you mean by "It seems like the selected item/value is bound to the itemssource"? I can't get any sense out of that sentence.

Comment: Actually, you're doing nothing with `SelectedValue` anywhere in your code.

Comment: The "Class" in the PropertyChanged is just a typo (from previous changes I did in the code). It should be PropertyChanged("Div") I'll correct it in the post. When it comes to my comment, I'm just guessing what's the problem because I really don't know why the comboboxes come out blank each time. I thought that maybe because the itemssource for the combobox dynamically changes based on the value that was actually entered into the Members collection, it causes it to affect the value that ends up being actually presented in the combobox.

Comment: So `Project.Members` is a collection of `Employee`. Each project has some number of `Members`, and you display them in a listbox. Each `Member` in that listbox gets a ComboBox full of all available Employees and... I guess you want to select the `Employee` in that ComboBox. Is the intent to let the user pick what employees are assigned to the project?

Comment: Yes. In case the user wants to swap one employee with another he/she could just replace the name in the combobox instead of delete the entry and enter a new one.

Comment: I think `SelectedValue="{Binding .}"` on the ComboBox would display the correct user, and get rid of the `Text="{Binding Name}"` thing on it. That'll display the name you want. I don't think it can update the collection.

Comment: I don't think this UI can work the way you want it to without some weird convolutions -- which I would strongly disrecommend at your level of experience with WPF. Or mine.

Comment: GAHHH I meant `SelectedItem="{Binding .}"`, whoops

Comment: Thanks, but neither really worked. The combobox still came out blank...

Comment: Are there any items in it?

Comment: In my test I just created some fake data and had 3 Employees: Bill, Bob, and Greg (FirstName property in Employee object) in the Employees property of Division. None of the names appear as a selected value in the combobox and also the drop-down of the combobox turns out blank.

Comment: Sorry, I should have asked that question first. Try `AncestorType=ListBox `  for the `ItemsSource` binding. I think `AvailableEmployees` is a property of `Project`, which is the `DataContext` of the `ListBox` that lists `Members`.

Comment: OK. Your idea solved the issue I had with the blank pop-up. Now the names finally appear. However, there is still a problem. Let's say that I have 3 employees: Bill, Bob, and Greg. When I start the app and add a new employee to the project, the box is blank, and if I try to change the selection I get only two options—Bob and Greg. This means that the selected item was Bill (first item) but it doesn't show in the combobox.

Comment: I gotta run. Can we revisit in a few hours?

Comment: Sure. Unless I find some other solution. Anyway, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Hey, if you find another solution, use it!

Comment: Hi, observable collections should NOT be replaceable. WPF and .NET does not handle that very well because they are observable, not replaceable. Remove the setters on the properties 'AvailableEmployees' and 'Members'. It is just silly to have them "writable" and can lead to unwanted bugs which will take your very long to debug. It may sometimes even solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK. After so many experiments the best solution I came up with was to create my own user control that is composed of both a button and a combobox that imitate the behavior I was expecting of the combobox on it own.

First, I had a really stupid mistake in the model where both lists of members Project and Division contain the same instances of Employee, which makes the AvailableEmployees property buggy. What I really needed to do is to create a list of copies of employees in the Project instead of just references.

In any case, I created a new user control and called it DynamicSourceComboBox. The XAML of this control looks like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="selected"
            Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:DynamicSourceComboBox}, Path=SelectedValue}"
            Click="selected_Click"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="selections"
              ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:DynamicSourceComboBox}, Path=ItemsSource}"
              DisplayMemberPath="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:DynamicSourceComboBox}, Path=DisplayMemberPath}"
              Visibility="Collapsed"
              SelectionChanged="selections_SelectionChanged"
              MouseLeave="selections_MouseLeave"/>
</Grid>
```

I have here a few bindings from the button and the combobox to properties in my user control. These are actually dependency properties. The code-behind of my user control looks like this:

```
public partial class DynamicSourceComboBox : UserControl
{
    public DynamicSourceComboBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public object SelectedValue
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(SelectedValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedValueProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedValue", typeof(object), typeof(DynamicSourceComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty.AddOwner(typeof(DynamicSourceComboBox));

    public string DisplayMemberPath
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DisplayMemberPathProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DisplayMemberPathProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayMemberPathProperty =
        ComboBox.DisplayMemberPathProperty.AddOwner(typeof(DynamicSourceComboBox));

    private void selected_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        selected.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        selections.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        selections.IsDropDownOpen = true;
    }

    private void selections_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        selections.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        selected.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        selections.IsDropDownOpen = false;

        if (e.AddedItems.Count == 1)
        {
            var item = e.AddedItems[0];

            Type itemType = item.GetType();
            var itemTypeProps = itemType.GetProperties();

            var realValue = (from prop in itemTypeProps
                            where prop.Name == DisplayMemberPath
                            select prop.GetValue(selections.SelectedValue)).First();

            SelectedValue = realValue;
        }  
    }

    private void selections_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        selections.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        selected.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        selections.IsDropDownOpen = false;
    }
}
```

These dependency properties imitate the properties with similar names in ComboBox but they are hooked up to the internal combobox and the button in a way that makes them behave together as a single complex combobox.

The Click event in the button hides it and present the combobox to make the effect of just a box that is opening. Then I have a SelectionChanged event in the combobox firing to update all the needed information and a MouseLeave event just in case the user doesn't make any real selection change.

When I need to use the new user control, I set it up like this:

```
<local:DynamicSourceComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType=ListBox}, Path=DataContext.AvailableEmployees}"
                                                                 DisplayMemberPath="FirstName"
                                                                 SelectedValue="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Of course, for all of it to work, I have to make a lot of hookups with PropertyChanged events in the models, so the Projects instance will know to raise a PropertyChanged event for AvailableEmployees any time a change is made, but this is not really the concern of this user control itself.

This is a pretty clunky solution, with a lot of extra code that is a bit hard to follow, but it's really the best (actually only) solution I could have come up with to the problem I had.